# JavaScript function that return with different types (Array vs NodeList)

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I wrote a JavaScript function that will return a "list" of elements that has Id that start with some value:

```
function getElementsWithIdPrefix(prefix){
    if (document.querySelectorAll){
        return document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="' + prefix + '"]');
    } else {
        // none modern browsers support
        var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
        var relevantElements = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
            if (element.id && element.id.indexOf(prefix) !== -1){
                relevantElements.push(element);
            }
        }
        return relevantElements;
    }
}
```

As you can see my function will return different types depends on browser support for `document.querySelectorAll` and I have two question regarding this:

1. Is this bad? I mean - In JavaScript typing system does it consider as a code smell or bad practice?
2. How can I create Node objects for each Element by my self and construct a new NodeList containing these elements to return?

Comment: Are you sure that `suffix` is right? Shouldn't it be `prefix`? If not, where is `suffix` coming from?

Comment: @Andy thanks for that, copy/pasted different version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this bad?

Probably, but it's probably a matter of opinion.

> How can I create Node objects for each Element by my self and construct a new NodeList containing these elements to return?

You can turn your QSA result into a true array like this:

```
return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="' + prefix + '"]'));
```

That way, you're returning an array in both cases.

---

Side note: You have to look pretty hard to find a browser that doesn't have QSA. It's on all modern browsers, and also IE8.

Side note 2: This line

```
if (element.id && element.id.indexOf(prefix) !== -1){
```

...doesn't look for a *prefix*. It looks for a substring match anywhere in the ID. For a prefix, use `=== 0` (or `element.id.substring(0, prefix.length) === prefix`).

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for the helpful side notes. This is exactly what I was looking for.